# store variable into GDBs variable in format as it was printed before

Tags: python, gdb

If I invoke print command in GDB the output is stored in some GDB's internal variable. But seems that this GDB's variable ignores the format in which the value was printed.

```
(gdb) p/t -123
$17 = 11111111111111111111111110000101
(gdb) p $17
$18 = -123 # I expected 11111111111111111111111110000101 instead of -123
```

Is it possible to somehow store actual value of `11111111111111111111111110000101` inside `$17` ?

PS: I would like this for further usage in custom python commands which will be invoked from GDB. I would like to type something like this and actually get an binary number inside python script (and use GDB `p/t` before as an decimal to binary converter).

```
(gdb) my_custom_python_command $1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to somehow store actual value of 11111111111111111111111110000101 inside $17

You appear to be confused.

The *actual* value is `-123` *when represented as a decimal number*, it is `111111111...` *when represented as an unsigned binary number*, and `-0x7B` *when represented as a signed hexadecimal number*.

The value and its representation in a specific format are separate concepts.

> I would like to type something like this and actually get an binary number inside python script

You *are* getting an actual binary number. If you want to get a string representation of this number, it's trivial to do so in Python.

```
python3 -c 'print(format((1<<32) + -123, "032b"))'
11111111111111111111111110000101
```